# Resta de campo y fecha actual

Tags: oracle

Tengo que crear una consulta en SQL Developer que me reste la fecha establecida en un campo con la fecha actual, devolviéndome minutos y horas.

La idea que tengo es más o menos así:

```
SELECT NAME, 
    (to_date(ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE) - to_date(SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL)) AS TIEMPOENCURSO 
FROM WORKREQUEST 
WHERE WORKREQUESTSTATEID != 17;
```

Pero claramente la parte de sysdate no me la toma porque está mal la sintaxis.

Alguna idea de cómo resolver esto? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Sysdate ya es un date, y hacer un select para traer sysdate no tendria sentido.. no podes restar simplemente sysdate?

Comment: Al traer solo sysdate me da todos números negativos

Comment: Podrias mostrar ejemplos de lo que estas haciendo?

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo algo rudimentario, no se si existe alguna manera de hacerlo mas simple:

Pero la idea es sacar las horas haciendo la resta de las fechas se obtiene el resultado en días, se multiplica por 24 para convertirlo a horas.

Y después concatenarlo con los minutos que quedan (la parte decimal que quita el trunc) por lo que hay que restar las horas que ya estamos sacando.

```
SELECT NAME, 
  trunc((SYSDATE- ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE)*24) --Las horas
  ||':'
  || trunc(((SYSDATE-ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE)-(trunc((SYSDATE- ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE)*24)/24))*24*60) AS TIEMPOENCURSO  --Los minutos, se les resta las horas completas
FROM WORKREQUEST 
WHERE WORKREQUESTSTATEID != 17;
```

Comment: Creo que esto me sirve, pero me está dando números muy grandes, hay workrequests que duraron 1 día nada más y me devuelve un número tipo "27806:46"

Comment: podrias hacer esta consulta mas simple y pegarme exactamente lo que te devuelve (solo el caso del que hablas que dura 1 dia y te saca ese numero)? `select ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE, sysdate from WORKREQUEST 
where WORKREQUESTSTATEID != 17`. Ademas de esto supongo que `ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE` es una columna tipo `DATE`, si no tendras que hacer un `to_date(ESTIMATEDCOMPLETEDATE)`

Comment: @MarianellaCabreraAhumada se me olvido nombrarte